# How can I set install_keras()'s virtualenv?

Tags: r, keras, reticulate

I created and set a virtualenv for install keras.

But it doesn't work.

When I command install_keras(tensorflow = "gpu") it always using virtual environment "~/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate".
I want to use "~/.virtualenvs/py3-virtualenv" but 'use_virtualenv("py3-virtualenv")' command doesn't work.

plz help me.....

This run on Ubuntu 18.04 and Rstudio-server.

```r
> rm(list=ls())
> # for linux ------------
> library(reticulate)
> virtualenv_list()
[1] "py3-virtualenv" "r-reticulate"   "scipy"         
> use_virtualenv("py3-virtualenv")
> # ----------------
> library(keras)
> install_keras(tensorflow = "gpu")
Using virtual environment '~/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate' ...
sh: 1: /home/bitl/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/pip: not found
error: Error installing package(s): 'pip'
```

I expect to work install_keras() function.

Comment: It is helpful for you [pip problem](https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-installing-python-libraries-with-reticulate-py-install-error-pip-not-found/26561)

Comment: @Sangwonkim Yes, I already read. of course it works when use "py_install()". but not works on "install_keras()"

Comment: How about reinstalling pip? In the same environment,  your case is a function is readable but the other function is unreadable. It seems collusion reading pip.